# How do I find the quadrant of a vector in the frame of an arbitrary axis?

Tags: c#, vector, cartesian-coordinates

I have three orthogonal normalized vectors BASE, SEARCH and AXIS

AXIS is an axis vector

BASE is a reference vector that doesn't change for the procedure.

SEARCH is a vector that will change over the range of 0 to 2 pi relative to the value of BASE

what I want is to get the angle between BASE and SEARCH

I know how to get the angle in the range of 0 to pi

If these were 2d coordinates I could use atan2() and add 2 pi if the value was negative but I don't know how to do that in the general 3d case.

If these vectors were 2d and the vector BASE was the X axis I could use the quadrant of SEARCH to determine to correct range.

I need this function

```
float AngleBetween(Vector3 Axis, Vector3 Base, Vector3 Search) {
    // use cross and dot to get 0 to pi angle
    // get quadrant of Search
    // adjust angle based on quadrant
}
```

thank you,

john

Comment: Wouldn't that be octants, unless we are in [Star Trek](https://www.reddit.com/r/DaystromInstitute/comments/39kp1p/shouldnt_the_quadrants_be_octants/)?

Comment: Because the base and search vectors form a plane if you look down the axis you will see an x y grid. By choosing base as the x axis then search will fall into a quadrant.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it.

Since the base vector doesn't move I can call it the X 2d axis.

Since I have a 3d axis vector I can rotate around it. What I do is to create the equivalent of the negative y 2d axis by rotating the Base vector 90 degrees clockwise around the 3d axis.

Then I have three vectors, the Search vector, the Base vector (x 2d axis) and -y 2d axis.

I compute two angles, one between the Search vector and the Base vector (x 2d axis) and one between the Search vector and the -y 2d axis.

Then I have enough to figure out the quadrant, because the angular distance between the two will vary between 0 and pi in a unique way.

if SB is the angle between the Search and the Base vector and SY is the angle between the Search and -Y (2d axis) then in a righthanded system (angles get larger counter clockwise) the rules are

1. if SB <= 90 && SY >= 90 this is the first quadrant
2. if SB >= 90 && SY >= 90 this is the second quadrant
3. if SB >= 90 && SY <= 90 this is the third quadrant
4. if SB <= 90 && SY <= 90 this is the fourth quadrant